# word swapping. Is swaw deprecated

Tags: c

I am using g++ on CodeBlocks 10.05 on Debian 7.0.0.

Back in the 90s, I wrote the following function to reverse the byte order in 4 byte integers.

```
/*******************************/
 void ByteSwapInt(int *ipInteger)
/*******************************/
 {
    int iBuffer;

    _swab( (char *)ipInteger, (char *)&iBuffer, 4 );
    swaw((char *)&iBuffer, (char *)ipInteger, 4);
 }
```

Up until recently, it has worked.  But I notice that swaw no longer appear to do anything.  I checked what was going on by making arrays of the individual bytes in *ipInteger and iBuffer by expanding the above function thus

```
/*******************************/
 void ByteSwapInt(int *ipInteger)
/*******************************/
 {
     int iBuffer;
     int Int[4], Buf[4];

    (Int[0]) = (*ipInteger >> 24) & 0xff;  // high-order (leftmost) byte: bits 24-31
    (Int[1]) = (*ipInteger >> 16) & 0xff;  // next byte, counting from left: bits 16-23
    (Int[2]) = (*ipInteger >>  8) & 0xff;  // next byte, bits 8-15
    (Int[3]) = *ipInteger         & 0xff;

    _swab( (char *)ipInteger, (char *)&iBuffer, 4 );
    (Buf[0]) = (iBuffer >> 24) & 0xff;  // high-order (leftmost) byte: bits 24-31
    (Buf[1]) = (iBuffer >> 16) & 0xff;  // next byte, counting from left: bits 16-23
    (Buf[2]) = (iBuffer >>  8) & 0xff;  // next byte, bits 8-15
    (Buf[3]) = iBuffer         & 0xff;
    swaw((char *)&iBuffer, (char *)ipInteger, 4);
    (Int[0]) = (*ipInteger >> 24) & 0xff;  // high-order (leftmost) byte: bits 24-31
    (Int[1]) = (*ipInteger >> 16) & 0xff;  // next byte, counting from left: bits 16-23
    (Int[2]) = (*ipInteger >>  8) & 0xff;  // next byte, bits 8-15
    (Int[3]) = *ipInteger         & 0xff;
 }
```

The content of *ipInteger does not change.  I tried unsiccessfully to find swaw, for swapping words, on google.  Is it deprecated?

Comment: It's certainly not in glibc. I'm not sure whether anyone can tell you if a function from a library you don't even remember is deprecated or not.

Comment: Welcome to the future: fortunately they still haven't killed `swab` see http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/string.h/swab.php

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I found a relatively simple fix in my answer.  I thought swaw was in unistd.h man "man swaw" returned no results on the Linux that came with Debian 7.0.0.  I think it was still available in Ubuntu 11.

Comment: Google finds no evidence it ever existed, so it must be deprecated? Imagine if deprecations worked that well.

Comment: Swaw() was a Novell Netware helper function.  Yup, time has not been kind to Netware, version 4 was a major mess.  Doc [is here](http://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/clib/?page=/documentation/developer/clib/prog_enu/data/sdk1677.html).  Note that it swapped words, 16-bit values.

Answer (score 3):

For networking you want `htonl`, `htons` and their companions `ntohl` and `ntohs`, being host-to-network and network-to-host transforms for 32-bit and 16-bit integers.  These will be defined appropriately for the architecture you're on.  Thus on SPARC they'd be a no-op (a big-endian platform) and on x86 they are implemented as swaps.  They're from `<arpa/inet.h>` or `<netinet/in.h>`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found was to use FIX_INT(x) described [here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/reading/).